# " 'System.Drawing.Image' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable' " in C# memory game

Tags: c#, memory

I was following a tutorial off YouTube on how to create a memory game in visual studio C# and the only error I get is the one in the title can someone please help me ? I really need it for an informatics project at school

```
using Memory_Game.Properties;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Memory_Game
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool _allowClick = true;
        private PictureBox _firstGuess;
        private readonly Random _random = new Random();
        private readonly Timer _clickTimer = new Timer();
        int ticks = 30;
        readonly Timer timer = new Timer { Interval = 1000 };

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetRandomImages();
            HideImages();
            StartGameTimer();
            _clickTimer.Interval = 1000;
            _clickTimer.Tick += _clickTimer_Tick;
        }

        private PictureBox [] PictureBoxes
        {
            get { return Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToArray(); }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Image> Images
        {
            get
            {
                return new Image[]
                {
                    Memory_Game.Properties.Resources.img1,
                    Memory_Game.Properties.Resources.img2,
                    Memory_Game.Properties.Resources.img3,
                    Memory_Game.Properties.Resources.img4,
                    Memory_Game.Properties.Resources.img5,
                    Memory_Game.Properties.Resources.img6,
                    Memory_Game.Properties.Resources.img7,
                    Memory_Game.Properties.Resources.img8

                };
            }
        }

        private void StartGameTimer()
        {
            timer.Start();
            timer.Tick += delegate
            {
                ticks--;
                if (ticks == -1)
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                    MessageBox.Show("Time's up.", "Memory Game", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                    ResetImages();
                }
                var time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ticks);
                lblTime.Text = "00:" + time.ToString("ss");
            };
        }

        private void ResetImages()
        {
            foreach (var pic in PictureBoxes)
            {
                pic.Tag = null;
                pic.Visible = true;
            }
            HideImages();
            SetRandomImages();
            ticks = 30;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void HideImages()
        {
            foreach (var pic in PictureBoxes)
            {
                pic.Image = Resources.img0;
                //pic.Image = (Image).pic.Tag; 
            }
        }

        private PictureBox GetFreeSlot()         ///functie ca imaginea sa apara de maxim 2 ori, nu de 3 sau asa
        {
            int num;
            do
            {
                num = _random.Next(0, PictureBoxes.Count());
            }
            while (PictureBoxes[num].Tag != null);
            return PictureBoxes[num];
        }


        private void SetRandomImages()
        {
            foreach (var image in Images)
            {
                GetFreeSlot().Tag = image;
                GetFreeSlot().Tag = image;
            }
        }


        private void ClickImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_allowClick)
                return;
            var pic = (PictureBox)sender;
            if (_firstGuess == null)
            {
                _firstGuess = pic;
                pic.Image = (Image)pic.Tag;
                return;
            }
            pic.Image = (Image).pic.Tag;
            if(pic.Image == _firstGuess.Image && pic != _firstGuess)
            {
                pic.Visible = _firstGuess.Visible = false;
                {
                    _firstGuess = pic;
                }
                HideImages();
            }
            else
            {
                _allowClick = false;
                _clickTimer.Start();
            }
            _firstGuess = null;
            if (PictureBoxes.Any(p => p.Visible)) return;
            MessageBox.Show("Ati Castigat !", "Memory Game", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            ResetImages();

        }

        private void _clickTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HideImages();
            _allowClick = true;
            _clickTimer.Stop();
        }
    }












}
```

Comment: On which line exactly?

Answer (score 3):

In the ClickImage method you have an extra `.`

Replace the line:

```
pic.Image = (Image).pic.Tag;
```

With

```
pic.Image = (Image)pic.Tag;
```

Comment: http://imgur.com/5XJYnLz here's a screenshot

Comment: It's because in your designer you have declared (maybe unintentionally) an event and a method with an empty body has been added to your code, then you deleted it but the event is still registered in your designer. You have to delete it by going into the Form properties. I answered this time but you should ask another question as it is off-topic.